# Spring Boot (ENTITY) - Expected to be able to resolve a type but got null! This usually stems from types implementing raw Map or Collection interfaces

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I got an error when I insert JSONObject in DTO for the result query

> Entity

```
@Entity
public class Inbound {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "manifestno_re")
    private String manifestNo;
    
    @Column(name = "manifestdate_re")
    private String manifestDate;
    
    @Column(name = "company_id_re")
    private String companyId;
    
    @Column(name = "driverscheduleId_re")
    private Integer DriverscheduleId;
    
    @Column(name = "childrenkoli_re")
    private JSONObject childrenkoli;
    }
```

when I run my project it give an error like my title. If I remove the childrenkoli_re, the program goes well

Comment: And what should `JSONObject` be mapped to? A varchar, blob, clob? There is no default mapping for that type, so you will need to create a usertype/converter yourself for this. Or better you probably shouldn't be storing the `JSONObject` but rather the `String` representation of that (but that is IMHO).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not any data type in the database which can directly store JSONObject so you need to specify the data type as varchar, blob, or clob or you can also modify the JSOObject in string and store it.
You can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6759448/json-object-from-database-in-java)